# Массив абстрактного класса. Как получить переменную из дочернего

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Создан класс списка из абстрактного класса:

```java
public class List {
    protected ArrayList <Transport> transports = new ArrayList();
}
```

Абстрактный класс:

```java
public abstract class Transport {
    protected String model;
    protected int price;
    protected int maxSpeed;
}
```

В списке я могу обращаться к переменным абстрактного класса:

```java
for (Transport transport: transports) {
    if(transport.price < 30000) {
        transport.print();
    }
}
```

Имеется дочерний класс, порождённый от абстрактного, со своими переменными:

```java
public class Car extends Transport {
    protected static String type = "Машина";
    protected int fuel;
    protected int fuel100km;
}
```

**Так вот вопрос, можно ли как-то обращаться из класса списка к переменным дочернего класса?**

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, вы хотите в цикле по транспорту вывести поля класса `Car` (`fuel`, `fuel100km`)?

Comment: Такое обращение в коде, который работает с базовым классом - это неправильный подход. Напишите, как именно вы хотите к ним "обращаться" и зачем. В общем опишите изначальную задачу. Изначальная задача, скорее всего, решается другим способом и вам не нужен доступ к наследникам.

Comment: Обратиться можно кастованием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Название класса `List` явно не слишком удачное, так как оно совпадает с названием интерфейса `List` из пакета `java.util`, что может привести к путанице/недоразумениям.
2. Сама по себе проблема обращения из класса-предка непосредственно к полям классов-потомков -- признак дурно пахнущего кода (code smell), так как класс предок **не должен** зависеть от свойств / методов, определённых в классах-потомках.

Корректный способ решения: определить в базовом классе некий абстрактный/виртуальный метод, который следует переопределить в потомках в зависимости от их реализации, и использовать необходимые поля потомка в таком методе/методах.

```java
public abstract class Transport {
    protected abstract boolean isOk();

    public void foo() {
        for (Transport transport: transports) {
            if (transport.price < 30000 && transport.isOk()) {
                transport.print();
            }
        }    
    }
    public void print() {
        // печатать поля класса-предка
    }
}

public class Car extends Transport {
    @Override
    protected boolean isOk() {
        return this.fuel > 10;
    }

    @Override
    public void print() { 
        super.print(); // напечатать поля класса-предка
        // напечатать поля данного класса-потомка
    }

}
```

---

НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЙ способ: проверять конкретный тип класса и приводить к типу класса-потомка для вызова его методов / полей.

```java
public class Transport {
    public void foo() {
        for (Transport transport: transports) {
            if (transport.price < 30000) {
                // так НЕ НАДО делать
                if (transport instanceof Car) {
                    Car car = (Car) transport;
                    car.fuel += 100500;
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```